# Encryption/Decryption key exchange PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm currently upgrading the security on one of the platforms I seal with. But, I am unable to crack how to securely store my encryption/decryption key.

Current setup:
MySQL server
Webserver

I need to store and read all sensitive data in the database using AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT. But, the key for which the data is encrypted/decrypted I would like to store securely. So, in the case where someone gains access to the database or the webserver, they won't be able easily guess the key combination or read it out of a config file.

The key can change depending on the data I need to read/write.

Is this at all possible? First option I thought of was just to use a key combination based on some columns on the data I needed to read. But, that makes it possible to guess by looking at the code if someone was to get hold of both source code & database.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you really want to make it secure, you can use something like a key management service. They store encryption keys (for example) on special drives and are the industry standard for storing keys (at least for what I know, correct me if I'm wrong). Of course they are not free but I just wanted to mention it for you to maybe look into this possibility.

Comment: @LLJ97 - I'm using AWS today. I've looked at https://aws.amazon.com/kms/ - is it something like this you're speaking of?

Comment: exactly. I was actually looking at aws too. That's a really secure way to store your keys.

Comment: @LLJ97 Thanks. I'm going with AWS KMS :) Fell free to add it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy and secure way to store your keys is by using a key management service like AWS KMS.

They (should) store keys on FIPS-140-2 validated hardware security modules which are designed for key storing and loading.

Online key management services do that in bulk and provide an api to use your key.

They are the industry standard and should be used to store keys securely since storing them in files or in the database can be secure but doesn't garantuee it.